# can't properly disable gl color material

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have scene with lighting that works fine. I want to addd a sky box that will fade away, so i am using

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

along with glColor4f to do this and it works fine. But for the fade to work i need to enable GL_COLOR_MATERIAL which completly gets rid of my lighting effects. I tried sandwiching the sky box part

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
(..light details..)

glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
(drawSkyBox)|
glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
(draw rest of scene)
```

but that just lets the fade work and still doesn't show my lighting. Oddly enough if do

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
(..light details..)

glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
(drawSkyBox)

(draw rest of scene)
```

I lose the fade and my lighting effects. Am I using GL_COLOR_MATERIAL properly? If I enable and disable right away, shouldn't there be no effect, leaving my lighting intact?

Comment: This makes it look like you have COLOR_MATERIAL enabled already.  Then when you disable it, your effects stop working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sky box probably shouldn't be affected by lighting.  There's nothing like a big shiny specularity on your sky and clouds to make it look very strange.  So it makes sense to disable lighting while you render that.  If lighting is off, the vertices just take whatever color you assign them (using glColor).

If lighting is on, the vertices will take on a combination of the lights' colors and the material properties.  You can set the ambient, diffuse, and specular color filters separately for each vertex and they'll be multiplied with the associated colors from the lights along with some other math to take into account direction and fall-off.  If, as is often the case, you're only changing the ambient and diffuse colors and you want them to be the same because you've already set the ambient and diffuse properties of your light source to both be white with the ambient significantly dimmer than the diffuse, then you can enable COLOR_MATERIAL and then setting glColor() is the same as calling glMaterial with GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE.